# what is Observables .map equivalent in promise for angular 7?

Tags: angular, promise

May i know how do i resolve a promise to "another" value that works like .map() in Observables?

```
new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(fileUrl).then(fileEntry => {
    fileEntry.getMetadata((metadata) => {
      if (metadata.size > 100000) {
        resolve('Max file size');
      }else{
        resolve(null);
      }
    })
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Observables .map run a transformation function over every item emitted down the stream. There is no promise equivalent of this, you would run the transformation function on the data before you resolved the promise with that data.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the way promises work there's not such a thing as a rxjs `.map()` operator, the only solution that I can think of is for you to manipulate the data the way you want it using a regular `.map()` inside of your `.then()`

**Array.prototype.map()**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map